# Ubuntu 22.04.3 software updater does not do upgrading

Tags: package-management

If you chose upgrade it does not do anything on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

[image]

with this options

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are running the long term support version of Ubuntu. The next available LTS release won't be ready for a few more months.

There may be a way to force an upgrade to a newer, non-LTS distro but why would you want to do that?

If you want to stay with the LTS distro track (recommended) change the setting for "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version to

[image]